# Bash Script To Move Files While Creating Directories

Tags: linux, bash, mv, mkdir

I've got this script to loop through all folders and move files that are more than 2 years old.  I'm using the install command because it creates the necessary directories on the destination path and then I remove the source.  I'd like to change the script to use the `mv` command since it is much faster than copying the file then deleting it.  But I don't know how to get the path without the filename to pass to the `mkdir -p` command?   How should I modify the script?

```
for d in *; do

find  "$d" -type f -mtime +730 -exec sh -c '

 echo "moving $d/{}" &&
 install -Dp "/data/Customer Files$d/{}" "/data/Customer Files Over 2 Years Old$d/{}" &&
 rm -f "/data/Customer Files$d/{}"' \;

done
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `dirname` but beware, if you give it a directory name it'll give you the path till the parent dir, maybe an example is easier:

> $ dirname /usr/bin/bash
> /usr/bin
>
> $ dirname /usr/bin
> /usr

Back to your script, the dirname subtlety does not come to play as you're searching for files. I'll simplified it a bit too, i didn't like the subshell, it's easier to parse for me without it. It becomes:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

SRC=./src
DST=./dst

for f in `cd $SRC && find . -type f -mtime +730`; do
    echo "moving $f"
    mkdir -p "$DST/`dirname $f`"
    mv "$SRC/$f" "$DST/$f"
done
```

Obviously you have to set SRC / DST as for your needs.

BTW, `mv` is faster then `cp` + `rm` when you're on the same filesystem FWIK.